# Regex - No match if trailing character is "-"

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex as below

```
^Schedule\s?(A|B|C|D|E|F|H|J|K|L|M|R|SE)?
```

so this will match anything like "**Schedule A** i need help".

I want restriction for the character "-" i.e it should not give a match if the string is like *"Schedule A - i need help"* .

But it should give a match if Schedule A is followed by anything other than a space and "-".

Comment: You should be able to use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the end: `(?! -)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative look aheads will be helpful here

```
^Schedule\s*([ABCDEFHJKLMR]|SE)(?!\s+-)
```

- `(?!\s+-)` Negative look ahead, checks if the matches string is not followed by space (`\s+`) and the `-`.
- **Note** The optional quantifiers `?` are not required as it causes the regex engine to skip them.
- `[ABCDEFHJKLMR]` Character class, matches a single character from this [set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eN9qB4/1)

Comment: `A|B|C|D|E|F|H|J|K|L|M|R` can be rewritten as `[ABCDEFHJKLMR]`